# Optimizing Python GDAL ReadAsArray

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy, array

I am using the GDAL ReadAsArray method to work with raster data using numpy (specifically reclassification). As my rasters are large, I process the arrays in blocks, iterating though each block and processing with a similar method to the [GeoExamples](http://geoexamples.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/gdal-performance-raster-classification.html) example.

I am now looking at how best to set the size of these blocks to optimize the time taken to process the whole raster. Being aware of the limitations with numpy array sizes, and the use of the GDAL GetBlockSize to use the "natural" block size of a raster, I have testing using a few different block sizes, made up of multiples of the "natural" size, with the example code below:

```
import timeit
try:
    import gdal
except:
    from osgeo import gdal

# Function to read the raster as arrays for the chosen block size.
def read_raster(x_block_size, y_block_size):
    raster = "path to large raster"
    ds = gdal.Open(raster)
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    xsize = band.XSize
    ysize = band.YSize
    blocks = 0
    for y in xrange(0, ysize, y_block_size):
        if y + y_block_size < ysize:
            rows = y_block_size
        else:
            rows = ysize - y
        for x in xrange(0, xsize, x_block_size):
            if x + x_block_size < xsize:
                cols = x_block_size
            else:
                cols = xsize - x
            array = band.ReadAsArray(x, y, cols, rows)
            del array
            blocks += 1
    band = None
    ds = None
    print "{0} blocks size {1} x {2}:".format(blocks, x_block_size, y_block_size)

# Function to run the test and print the time taken to complete.
def timer(x_block_size, y_block_size):
    t = timeit.Timer("read_raster({0}, {1})".format(x_block_size, y_block_size),
                     setup="from __main__ import read_raster")
    print "\t{:.2f}s\n".format(t.timeit(1))

raster = "path to large raster"
ds = gdal.Open(raster)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Get "natural" block size, and total raster XY size. 
block_sizes = band.GetBlockSize()
x_block_size = block_sizes[0]
y_block_size = block_sizes[1]
xsize = band.XSize
ysize = band.YSize
band = None
ds = None

# Tests with different block sizes.
timer(x_block_size, y_block_size)
timer(x_block_size*10, y_block_size*10)
timer(x_block_size*100, y_block_size*100)
timer(x_block_size*10, y_block_size)
timer(x_block_size*100, y_block_size)
timer(x_block_size, y_block_size*10)
timer(x_block_size, y_block_size*100)
timer(xsize, y_block_size)
timer(x_block_size, ysize)
timer(xsize, 1)
timer(1, ysize)
```

Which produces the following sort of output:

```
474452 blocks size 256 x 16:
        9.12s

4930 blocks size 2560 x 160:
        5.32s

58 blocks size 25600 x 1600:
        5.72s

49181 blocks size 2560 x 16:
        4.22s

5786 blocks size 25600 x 16:
        5.67s

47560 blocks size 256 x 160:
        4.21s

4756 blocks size 256 x 1600:
        5.62s

2893 blocks size 41740 x 16:
        5.85s

164 blocks size 256 x 46280:
        5.97s

46280 blocks size 41740 x 1:
        5.00s

41740 blocks size 1 x 46280:
        800.24s
```

I have tried running this for a few different rasters, with different sizes and pixel types, and appear to be getting similar trends, where a ten fold increase in the x or y dimension (in some cases, both) halves the processing time, which although not that significant in the example above, can mean a number of minutes for my largest rasters.

So my question is, why is this behavior occurring?

I did expect using fewer blocks to improve processing time, but the tests using the least are not the quickest. Also, why does the final test take so much longer than the one preceding it? Is there some kind of preference with rasters for reading by row or column, or in the shape of the block being read, the total size? What I'm hoping to get from this is the information to get a basic algorithm together that will be able to set the block size of a raster to an optimal value, depending on the size of the input.

Note that my input is an ESRI ArcINFO grid raster, which has a "natural" block size of 256 x 16, and the total size of my raster in this example was 41740 x 46280.

Comment: Amazing  test! help a lot! cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using an equal blocksize. I deal with raster data which is of the order of 200k x 200k pixels and quite sparse. A lot of benchmarking has yielded 256x256 pixels blocks as most efficient for our processes. This is all to do with how many disk seeks are required to retrieve a block. If the block is too large then it is harder to write it to disk contiguously, meaning more seeks. Likewise, if it is too small, you will need to do many reads to process the whole raster. It also helps to ensure the total size is a power of two. 256x256 is incidentally the default geotiff block size in gdal, so perhaps they drew the same conclusion

Comment: Blocks of 256 x 256 were a little quicker than most other tests (and equal to 2560 x 16 and 41740 x 1), but only by about 5%. However, by converting my raster to geotiff format, it was the fastest option by at least 20%, so for tiffs at least that looks to be a good choice of block size. My gdal had the default geotiff blocksize at 128 x 128, though.

Comment: Yes, if you have the choice of formats geotiff is the best option - by far the most development time has been put into this driver. Also experiment with compression, and if your data is sparse (lots of null values) you should look at using the SPARSE_OK creation option and skip reading/writing null blocks

Comment: Good to know for future reference, although I'm stuck with reading ESRI ArcINFO grids for the given example.

Comment: Also, for the difference between the final two examples, you will want to read about row major order vs column major order. Again, it comes down to how many disk seeks are required to construct the requested block.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is you're really bumping up against GDAL's block cache, and that's a knob that's going to have a significant impact on your processing speed curve.

See [SettingConfigOptions](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#SettingConfigOptions), specifically `GDAL_CACHEMAX`, for more detail on this and investigate how changing that value to something significantly larger interacts with your simulation.

Comment: After setting the cache to 1 GB with gdal.SetCacheMax(1000000000), there was a few seconds decrease across most tests, except the final 1 x ysize one, which sped up to 40s. Decreasing the cache to 1 mb actually speeds up all tests but the last two. I think this is because I'm using the natural block size for most of the tests, and have no overlapping blocks, so the cache isn't needed except for the final two tests.