# Create map (image) from raster and vector in Python - problem with big files

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector, matplotlib

I wrote function which allows me to plot raster and (optionally) plot vector on the same image.
It works for small files, but in case of big rasters, I receive memmory error.

I've tried to add conditional statement to handle big rasters according to response in:
[Python/GDAL--Handling Big Rasters and avoid MemoryErrors?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211611/python-gdal-handling-big-rasters-and-avoid-memoryerrors)

However it doesn't work properly, I still receive an error message.

Could you help? Here is my Code:

```
def createMap(raster, vmax, vmin, output, shapefile=None, title=None):
    ###################################################################
    # Creates image from raster and shapefile
    # Based on: https://gist.github.com/jdherman/7434f7431d1cc0350dbe
    ######
    # TODO: Consider rewriting to pyQGIS
    # (http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html)
    #####
    # Prerequisities:
    # sudo apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
    ##################################################################
    ## Sample files for testing (comment in gedit: CTRL + M, uncomment: CTRL + SHIFT + M)
    #import os
    #from os.path import expanduser
    #home = expanduser("~")

    #SMOSfile = os.path.join(home,"Dropbox/Dane SMOS CATDS dla Wisły/DA_TC_MIR_CL_33/EXT-SM_RE02_MIR_CLF33A_20101231T000000_20120102T235959_272_001_7/ext-SM_RE02_MIR_CLF33A_20101231T000000_20120102T235959_272_001_7_1.DBL.nc")
    #SMOSraster = 'NETCDF:"' + SMOSfile + '":Soil_Moisture'
    #SentinelRaster = os.path.join(home,"Testy/calibrated_S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20160512T161044_20160512T161.data/Sigma0_VH.img")
    #vmin = 0
    #vmax = 3000
    #output = os.path.join(home,"testy.png")
    #shapefile = os.path.join(home,"Dropbox/mapy/dorzecze_Wisły")
    #createMap(SMOSraster, vmax, vmin, output, shapefile)
    #createMap(SentinelRaster, vmax, vmin, output)
    ###################################################################

    from osgeo import gdal, osr
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

    # By default, osgeo.gdal returns None on error, and does not normally raise informative exceptions
    gdal.UseExceptions()

    gdata = gdal.Open(raster)
    geo = gdata.GetGeoTransform()

    xres = geo[1]
    yres = geo[5]

    # Get "natural" block size, and total raster XY size. 
    band = gdata.GetRasterBand(1)
    block_sizes = band.GetBlockSize()
    x_block_size = block_sizes[0]
    y_block_size = block_sizes[1]
    xsize = band.XSize
    ysize = band.YSize
    print('x_block_size: {0}, y_block_size: {1}.'.format(x_block_size, y_block_size))
    print('xsize: {0}, ysize: {1}.'.format(xsize, ysize))

    if (xsize < 5000):
        data = gdata.ReadAsArray()
    else:
        #########################################################
        ## TODO: for big rasters such as Sentinel-1:
        ## Solution adapted from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211611/python-gdal-handling-big-rasters-and-avoid-memoryerrors
        ## It seems that I still receive Memory Error 
        y_block_size_NEW = int(round(y_block_size/200)) if y_block_size > 200 else y_block_size
        x_block_size_NEW = int(round(x_block_size/200)) if x_block_size > 200 else x_block_size

        # Create temporal raster
        raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(gdata.GetProjectionRef())

        format = "GTiff"
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( format )
        # TODO: seems that I should create smaller temporal raster (?)
        dst_ds = driver.Create("original_blocks.tif", xsize, ysize, 1, band.DataType )

        dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geo)
        dst_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

        blocks = 0 
        for y in xrange(0, ysize, y_block_size_NEW):
            #print blocks
            if y + y_block_size_NEW < ysize:
                rows = y_block_size_NEW
            else:
                rows = ysize - y
            for x in xrange(0, xsize, x_block_size_NEW):
                if x + x_block_size_NEW < xsize:
                    cols = x_block_size_NEW
                else:
                    cols = xsize - x
                # Seems that some kind of average should be calculated here
                array = band.ReadAsArray(x, y, cols, rows)
                try:
                    array[array>0]=1
                    #print "we got them"
                except:
                    print "could not find them"
                dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array, x, y)
                del array
                blocks += 1

        data = dst_ds.ReadAsArray()
        # TODO: Remove temporal raster?
        #########################################################

    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=17.00,llcrnrlat=48.75,urcrnrlon=25.25,urcrnrlat=54.50)

    if shapefile is not None:
        m.readshapefile(shapefile,'shp',drawbounds=True, color='0.3')
    xmin = geo[0] + xres * 0.5
    xmax = geo[0] + (xres * gdata.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
    ymin = geo[3] + (yres * gdata.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
    ymax = geo[3] - yres * 0.5
    x,y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax+xres:xres, ymax+yres:ymin:yres]
    x,y = m(x,y)
    cmap = plt.cm.gist_rainbow
    cmap.set_under ('1.0')
    cmap.set_bad('0.8')
    im = m.pcolormesh(x,y, data.T, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
    cb = plt.colorbar( orientation='vertical', fraction=0.10, shrink=0.7)
    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.savefig(output)
```

Comment: It seems like the else block is splitting the data into separate chunks before putting it back together again, so that nothing has actually changed by the time "dst_ds.ReadAsArray()" is called. Could you rewrite it so that multiple datasets are created and then plot these individually? Also making the blocksize 1/200 of the original is probably excessive unless the dataset is truly massive, maybe it would be better to split the image in 2*2 or 3*3 blocks.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Will plotting of those pieces separately not overwrite previously plotted piece? I'm not sure if I also need such level of details - will it not be easier to generalize/simplify raster, so that it will be easier to ReadAsArray()?

Comment: If you don't need the full resolution then the easiest solution will be to resample the image to a lower resolution. You can do this with gdal warp from the command line:    gdalwarp -of gtiff -tr 100 100 input_name.tif output_name.tif